# How to call a JavaScript function from C# code-behind for Highcharts Events (9.3.2.1) - .NET Runtime (v4.0.30319)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, visual-studio, highcharts

I have a Highcharts implementation on ASP.NET with C# code behind. All my charts are populated from the C# code-behind and not client side via Javascript.
I have a function that will synchronize the zoom level on all the charts if one chart is zoomed.

```
function syncExtremes(e) {
            var thisChart = this.chart;

            const shouldShowResetZoom = !(e.min === undefined && e.max === undefined);

            if (e.trigger !== 'syncExtremes') { // Prevent feedback loop
                Highcharts.each(Highcharts.charts, function (chart) {
                    if (chart !== thisChart) {
                        if (chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes) { // It is null while updating
                            chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(
                                e.min,
                                e.max,
                                undefined,
                                false,
                                { trigger: 'syncExtremes' }
                            );
                        }
                    }

                    if (shouldShowResetZoom && !chart.resetZoomButton) {
                        chart.showResetZoom();
                    } else if (!shouldShowResetZoom && chart.resetZoomButton) {
                        chart.resetZoomButton = chart.resetZoomButton.destroy();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

This function is purely JavaScript. I want to call this function on the X-Axis Events (SetExtremes) but I have no idea how to do it. I tried many different ways, none seems to work.
Can someone perhaps extend an example on how to call a function on the SetExtremes() event **from C# code behind.**

I have many examples where this done from the Client Side when the chart is created Client Side via Javascript, but this doesn't help me.

This my chart in the C# code behind.

```
       // Small Temp Chart Overlay

       chartTemp = new Highcharts("chartTemp").InitChart(new Chart
       {
         ZoomType = ZoomTypes.Xy,
         Height = 320,
         MarginTop = 100
       })
      .SetPlotOptions(options)
      .SetXAxis(new XAxis
      {
          Type = AxisTypes.Datetime,
          Title = new XAxisTitle { Text = "Date / Time" },
          //TickInterval = getTickInterval(txtStartDate.Text, txtEndDate.Text, "Normal"),
          TickmarkPlacement = Placement.On,
          Labels = new XAxisLabels
          {
              Formatter = @"function(){if((this.axis.getExtremes().max - this.axis.getExtremes().min) <= 86400000) {return Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M', this.value);} if((this.axis.getExtremes().max - this.axis.getExtremes().min) > 86400000 && (this.axis.getExtremes().max - this.axis.getExtremes().min) <= 1728000000) {return Highcharts.dateFormat('%m/%e %H:%M', this.value);} if((this.axis.getExtremes().max - this.axis.getExtremes().min) > 1728000000 && (this.axis.getExtremes().max - this.axis.getExtremes().min) <= 25920000000) {return Highcharts.dateFormat('%m/%e', this.value);} if((this.axis.getExtremes().max - this.axis.getExtremes().min) > 25920000000) {return Highcharts.dateFormat('%m/%y', this.value);}}",
              //Rotation = setRotation(),
              //Y = 30,
          },
          TickPositioner = TickPositionerLarge,
          Events = { SetExtremes = "syncExtremes" }
          //Events = { SetExtremes = "syncExtremes(e)" }
          //Events = { SetExtremes = "{ trigger: 'syncExtremes' }" }
      })

      .SetCredits(new Credits { Enabled = false })
      .SetSeries(new Series[]
      {
         new Series { Name = "Temperature", Data = new Data(mynewArray), Type = ChartTypes.Line, Color = Color.Red }
      })
      .SetTitle(new Title
      {
          Text = "Temperature",
          Align = HorizontalAligns.Center,
          Style = "fontSize: '16px',fontFamily: 'Rockwell'"
      })
      .SetLegend(new Legend { Enabled = false })
      .SetYAxis(yAxis[0])
      
      .SetSubtitle(new Subtitle
      {
          //Text = "Minimum Distance: " + YMin.ToString() + "mm; Maximum Distance: " + YMax.ToString() + "mm",
          Align = HorizontalAligns.Center
      });
            ltrChartTemperature.Text = chartTemp.ToHtmlString();
```

On the ASP client side, I just have a literal component:

```
<div id="container1">
  <asp:Literal ID="ltrChartTemperature" runat="server"> </asp:Literal>
</div>
```

The chart(s) work perfectly, I just need a solution for the synchronous Zoom.
Any advice would be much appreciated

Comment: Try this way: `Events =  { SetExtremes = "function(e){syncExtremes(e)}" }`

Comment: @magdalena - Thank you so much. I do however still get the object reference not set to an instance of an object error. I get this when I specify ANY string. Even just "1". So not sure what the SetExtremes Event String expects.

Comment: You can see the error here:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AonnEg1PRAjbnOVvfRt_8jhv6zYq2A?e=praaxk

Comment: Any other idea on how to sync the zoom level between charts from C# code behind perhaps?

Comment: I tested it again and in my case, everything works correctly. It seems like you don't use the official .NET wrapper (https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/your-first-chart-with-highcharts-net-and-net-core/), so it might be due to a third-party plugin. In that case, I would recommend reporting the issue on the proper wrapper's site or using the official and supported wrapper.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using the "Highcharts" dll and not the "HighchartsStandard" one. I will make a backup and try with the latter. Will let you know. Thanks